# How to write an awk script?

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to figure out how to write a standalone awk script file.

I thought it would be similar to a standalone bash script file:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f      
BEGIN{
    for  (i  =  0;  i  <  ARGC;  i++)
        printf  "%s  ",  ARGV[i]
    printf  "\n"
}
{print $0}
```

1. I was trying to figure out how the command line arguments are
   specified in shell, and passed into the script:

   ```
   $ myscript.awk arg1 arg2 arg3
   awk  arg1  arg2  arg3  
   awk: /home/tim/myscript.awk:5: fatal: cannot open file `arg1' for reading (No such file or directory)
   ```

   What does an awk script expect its command line arguments to be? Why
   does it expect `arg1`  to be the input file?

   Command line arguments are passed into an awk script, and stored in array ARGV. See my udpate. So I suppose the command line arguments are interpreted up to the script, not to`awk`.
2. If I remove `-f` in the shebang, i.e. `#! /usr/bin/awk`

   ```
   $ myscript.awk arg1 arg2 arg3
   awk: cmd. line:1: /home/tim/myscript.awk
   awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
   ```

   Why is `-f` necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect `arg1` to be (or want it to be)? `awk` always takes the target filenames as arguments.

Comment: command line arguments are passed into an awk script, and stored in array `ARGV`. See my udpate. So I suppose the command line arguments are interpreted up to the script, not to `awk`.

Comment: And `{print $0}` is expected to be operating on...?

Comment: @Michael So input files must be specified, and must be specified as command line arguments. Are all the command line arguments   expected to be input filenames? Can there be some command line arguments which are not input files but are interpreted up to the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does an awk script expect its command line arguments to be? Why does it expect arg1 to be the input file?

`awk`'s pattern based rules need input. When processing of this parts of your program starts, `awk` starts to consume arguments as filenames (or stdin if no filenames are given).

Before this step you can do whatever you want with given argments in the `BEGIN` block.

I think, these small examples get you started:

```
$ cat a.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        i=1
        while( i in ARGV )
                print ARGV[i++]
}
```

`a.awk` only has a `BEGIN` block and no pattern based rules. `awk` does not need files and so does not use the given arguments as filenames:

```
$ ./a.awk poit --zort -troz narf
poit
--zort
-troz
narf
```

It is your decision what to do with these.

If you want to have pattern based rules processing files given as arguments too, you need to delete all arguments you have used in your `BEGIN` block:

```
$ cat b.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        if( ARGV[1] == "--tolower" ) { cmd = "tr A-Z a-z" ; delete ARGV[1] }
        else if( ARGV[1] == "--toupper" ) { cmd = "tr a-z A-Z" ; delete ARGV[1] }
        else cmd = "cat"
}
{
        print | cmd
}
```

Example run without option:

```
$ ./b.awk a.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        i=1
        while( i in ARGV )
                print ARGV[i++]
}
```

Example run with `--toupper` option:

```
$ ./b.awk --toupper a.awk
#!/USR/BIN/AWK -F
BEGIN {
        I=1
        WHILE( I IN ARGV )
                PRINT ARGV[I++]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what you meant by "if stdin already is fully used up"?

Comment: `awk` can use stdin as input but I mixed something up. It uses stdin (like in `echo 'Hi!' | awk '{ print}'`) only if there are *no* filenames given as arguments. `man mawk` writes: "If `ARGC` equals 1, the input stream is set to stdin, else  the command line arguments `ARGV[1]` ... `ARGV[ARGC-1]` are examined for a file argument."

Comment: AAAahhhhh! Now I got it again... \o/ ...yesterday I asked myself why I have put the whole [`ncomm`](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1668424) only in a `BEGIN` block. Some of its functionality looks like just right for pattern based rules. But: Bingo! Pattern based rules would allow stdin as input which would make no sense here because it only would be the only "file" and even would not give me a filename for the header of the output. Well... no program should be too short for some comments or documentation... I'll let `awk` write this 1000 times for me... ;-)

Comment: With some `awk` implementations, that `--toupper` would be taken as an option to `awk`, not the `awk` script, so portably, you'd need to invoke your script as `./b.awk -- --toupper a.awk`, `--` marking the end-of-options for `awk`, so the `--toupper` be passed as an argument to the script. In any awk implementation, you'll have a problem with options that happen to be valid awk options.

Comment: (a) That's really mean! Which behaviour is defined for this in the original `awk`? (b) That does not change that you need to delete every `ARGV[*]` your `BEGIN` block used if you don't want it to be reused as filename for pattern rules. So if that turns out to be a major problem, maybe the "delete used args example" should not show something related to options...

Answer (score 6):

AWK expects its arguments to be either a script’s text, or `-f` followed by the name of a file containing the script to run, in both cases optionally followed by the names of the files to process.

This explains why you need `-f` in the shebang line: without that, AWK considers that your script’s filename is itself the AWK statements to run.

Regarding argument processing, an AWK program can do its own argument processing if it wishes. Your script fails because of the `{print $0}` line: this instructs the interpreter to read each line from its input (the files named on the command line, since you’ve specified some) and process it according to the instructions in the block. If you remove that line you won’t get any errors. You can process arguments in `BEGIN` and clean up `ARGV` so that it only contains input files; then AWK won’t complain.

Trying to do your own argument and input processing entirely, would probably mean ignoring a lot of what makes AWK so useful; if you want to do that you might as well use Perl.

(Note that the shebang handling means you can store simple AWK scripts in their filename, which avoids having to find clever names for scripts — not that anyone should do that...)

Comment: Thanks. Is the syntax of Perl more similar to awk or to sed?

Comment: Thanks.    I was wondering what you mean by    "  shebang handling means you can store simple AWK scripts in their filename, which avoids having to find clever names for scripts — not that anyone should do that..."? Thanks.

Comment: Perl is much closer to AWK than to sed. My note was perhaps a too-clever comment pointing out that you can write a script called `{ print NF }` containing only `#!/usr/bin/awk`, and it will work (if it’s on your path). That’s not specific to AWK of course, it works with any interpreter capable of interpreting commands given as arguments to it (including the shell, with `-c`).

Comment: A problem with `#! /usr/bin/awk -f` is that if you pass options (arguments starting with `-`, though that's limited to options recognised by awk with some awk implementations) to the script, they will be interpreted _as awk options_ (not arguments to the  script). There are also potential problems with arguments containing `=` characters. See `#! /usr/bin/gawk -E` to work around those.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas To distinguish awk options and  arguments to the script, is it a way to process those elements in ARGV that  are meant for the script in BEGIN block?

Comment: @Tim, no in `awk -f script --help` with `gawk` for instance, the `--help` doesn't make it to the script, the `script` is not even run, awk displays its help message

Answer (score 5):

An `awk` script expects its non-option command line arguments to be filenames of files upon which the script should act (if none are given, it acts on standard input).

So when you use `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` in an `awk` script file, this tells the system that the text of the file itself should be passed on to `awk -f`. Any other command line arguments will be interpreted as input files or as additional flags to `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    for (i in ARGV) {
        printf("ARGV[%d] = %s\n", i, ARGV[i]);
    }
    printf("var = %s\n", var);
}

$ ./script.awk -vvar=hello ~/.profile
ARGV[0] = awk
ARGV[1] = /home/kk/.profile
var = hello
```

Command line checks for options ends at the first non option argument:

```
$ ./script.awk ~/.profile -vvar=hello
ARGV[2] = -vvar=hello
ARGV[0] = awk
ARGV[1] = /home/kk/.profile
var =
```

For `awk` to be useful for anything, it needs input data.  This data usually comes from one or several input files named on the command line, or from sending data on the standard input stream.

Apart from the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks, each block in an `awk` script will be applied to each record (each line by default) of the input data in turn.